# YAML multi-line signifier not working in Jekyll data file

Tags: string, yaml, jekyll

According to the YAML syntax the `>` symbol should allow the value to span multiple lines:

```
- name: coming-soon
  teaser: >
  “Dolor eiusmod cupidatat duis qui consectetur. 
  Mollit nulla consectetur id excepteur do. 
  Anim ut dolor quis sit consequat. 
  Mollit laboris proident sunt incididunt mollit consequat officia. 
  Ad deserunt eu veniam qui eiusmod ex proident 
  pariatur tempor mollit laborum enim laboris elit.”
```

But it is resulting the following error in Jekyll:

```
could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 11 column 3
```

The `:` is clearly there so I don't know what's causing it to fail. Has anyone come across this before?

I've tried putting all the lines in double quote and single quotes. I've tried removing the quotes altogether. I've tried using `>-` instead of `>` but all of them produce the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is introduced by the `>` is a [folded style block scalar](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2796251), as indicated in the spec, it is similar to the literal style scalar so you can rewrite its description to match the folded style:

> Inside folded scalars, all (indented) characters are considered to be content, including white space characters. Note that all line break characters are normalized.

What is clearly missing is the **indentation**, which determines what lines belong to this value for the key `teaser`. If there were a following key, it would have to be the first thing aligned with `teaser` again. But your whole folded scalar is aligned, and that confuses the YAML parser.

I am not sure if you want the double quotes to be part of the value, if you do you should use:

```
- name: coming-soon
  teaser: >
    “Dolor eiusmod cupidatat duis qui consectetur. 
    Mollit nulla consectetur id excepteur do. 
    Anim ut dolor quis sit consequat. 
    Mollit laboris proident sunt incididunt mollit consequat officia. 
    Ad deserunt eu veniam qui eiusmod ex proident 
    pariatur tempor mollit laborum enim laboris elit.”
```

(the amount of spaces is not important, but make sure every line is aligned, otherwise you have to specify the indent after the `>`).

If your double quotes are **not** part of the value, you can use the folded scalar:

```
- name: coming-soon
  teaser: >
    Dolor eiusmod cupidatat duis qui consectetur. 
    Mollit nulla consectetur id excepteur do. 
    Anim ut dolor quis sit consequat. 
    Mollit laboris proident sunt incididunt mollit consequat officia. 
    Ad deserunt eu veniam qui eiusmod ex proident 
    pariatur tempor mollit laborum enim laboris elit.
```

Or leave out the folding and use a multi-line plain scalar:

```
- name: coming-soon
  teaser: Dolor eiusmod cupidatat duis qui consectetur. 
    Mollit nulla consectetur id excepteur do. 
    Anim ut dolor quis sit consequat. 
    Mollit laboris proident sunt incididunt mollit consequat officia. 
    Ad deserunt eu veniam qui eiusmod ex proident 
    pariatur tempor mollit laborum enim laboris elit.
```

Answer (score -1):

When it doubt...
Indent!

```
- name: coming-soon
  teaser: >
    Dolor eiusmod cupidatat duis qui consectetur. 
    Mollit nulla consectetur id excepteur do. 
    Anim ut dolor quis sit consequat. 
    Mollit laboris proident sunt incididunt mollit consequat officia. 
    Ad deserunt eu veniam qui eiusmod ex proident 
    pariatur tempor mollit laborum enim laboris elit.
```

Comment: In a block scalar [content may safely start with a tab](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2793979), and to maintain portability [tab characters must not be used in indentation](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2777534). The advice to start adding tabs is about as bad as can be.